# How to render multiple mysql queries using node in one http request

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I need to make two query's from different tables, how should i do it, to output data in new page. Now it is working with one query.

```
exports.getAllImages = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_group='TRENCH 
CONVECTORS'", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

//This is what i tried, but it does not work
router.get('/product/:id', async function(req, res, next) {
  let filesFromFolder;
  let allimages
  database.retreaveImage(req.params.id).then(function(value) {
    filesFromFolder = value;

  });
  database.getAllImages().then(function(value){
    allimages = value;
  })

  res.render('product.ejs', {
    productName: req.params.id,
    data: filesFromFolder,
    allimages: allimages
  });
});

//This code works, and i am using it now
router.get('/product/:id', async function(req, res, next) {
  let filesFromFolder;
  database.retreaveImage(req.params.id).then(function(value) {
    filesFromFolder = value;
    res.render('product.ejs', {
      productName: req.params.id,
      data: filesFromFolder
    });
  });
});
```

How should i edit the code to execute two query's?

Comment: Research SQL `JOIN` assuming the tables have relations to one and other: if you can't work it out see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland ok now i understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to render your page when you received response from both queries.
You can use Promise.all() method for this.

```
Promise.all([
  database.retreaveImage(req.params.id),
  database.getAllImages()
]).then(resultArr => {
  filesFromFolder = resultArr[0];
  allimages = resultArr[1];

  res.render("product.ejs", {
    productName: req.params.id,
    data: filesFromFolder,
    allimages: allimages
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want a single query who retrieve data from two tables or if you want 2 different queries from 2 table...if the second, you can concatenate functions to have a linear flow of data

```
//This code works, and i am using it now
router.get('/product/:id/:temp', async function(req, res, next) {
  let filesFromFolder;
  database.retreaveImage(req.params.id).then(function(value) {

    var filesFromFolder = value;        

    //Using a temp function
    database.retreaveTemp(req.params.temp).then(function(value_temp) {

        var filesFromTemp = value_temp;

        res.render('product.ejs', {
           productName: req.params.id,
           data: filesFromFolder,
           dataTemp: filesFromTemp 
       });
    });
  });
});
```